# PHP多次元配列から階層リストタグ<ul><li></li><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>を出力したい

Tags: php, html

元データhogeAry
・子に対する親を parent_id で指定
・親は parent_id = 0

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hoge_id] => 2
            [hoge] => 親2
            [parent_id] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [hoge_id] => 3
            [hoge] => 子2-1
            [parent_id] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [hoge_id] => 4
            [hoge] => 子7-1
            [parent_id] => 7
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [hoge_id] => 7
            [hoge] => 親7
            [parent_id] => 0
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [hoge_id] => 1
            [hoge] => 親1
            [parent_id] => 0
        )
 )
```

希望出力結果

```
<ul>
  <li>親1</li>
  <li>親2
    <ul>
      <li>子2-1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>親7
    <ul>
      <li>子7-1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 現在までにどのようなコードを書いて、うまくいっていないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

他の方のアプローチのように、表示したい構造に合わせた木構造に変換してから表示用の組み立て処理を行うのも手ですが、今回示されているデータはある意味すでに木構造を表していますので、わざわざ表示向けのデータ構造に変換しないアプローチでもよいかと思います。

下のコードでは、基本的な再帰のアプローチで、都度対象となる子を抽出してきてタグを組み立てています。

```
<?php

$data = [
    [
        'hoge_id' => 2,
        'hoge' => '親2',
        'parent_id' => 0,
    ],
    [
        'hoge_id' => 8,
        'hoge' => '孫',
        'parent_id' => 4,
    ],
    [
        'hoge_id' => 3,
        'hoge' => '子2-1',
        'parent_id' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'hoge_id' => 4,
        'hoge' => '子7-1',
        'parent_id' => 7,
    ],
    [
        'hoge_id' => 7,
        'hoge' => '親7',
        'parent_id' => 0,
    ],
    [
        'hoge_id' => 1,
        'hoge' => '親1',
        'parent_id' => 0,
    ]
];

class HtmlUlBuilder
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function buildFromParent($parent_id)
    {
        $children = array_filter($this->data, function ($element) use ($parent_id) {
            return $element['parent_id'] === $parent_id;
        });

        if (count($children) === 0) return '';

        return '<ul>' . array_reduce($children, function ($current, $element) {
            return $current . PHP_EOL . '<li>' . $element['hoge'] . $this->buildFromParent($element['hoge_id']) . '</li>';
        }, '') . '</ul>';
    }
}

usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['hoge_id'] > $b['hoge_id'];
});

$builder = new HtmlUlBuilder($data);
$html = $builder->buildFromParent(0);

echo $html;
```

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。array_reduceを初めて知りました。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 2):

現状で細かい条件などが示されていないので、とりあえず例示されているデータでちゃんと出来るように適当に組んでみました。
`$data` に例示された配列としてみてください。

```
/**
 * hoge_id を比較して昇順にする.
 * @param array $a 左辺
 * @param array $b 右辺
 * @return integer $a['hoge_id'] が $b より大きい時は 1. $b['hoge_id'] が $a 以下の時は -1 を返す.
 */
function id_cmp( array $a, array $b )
{
    return ($a['hoge_id']>$b['hoge_id']) ? 1 : -1;
}
// リストデータ作成.
$listed_data = array();
foreach( $data as $datum )
{
    // もしなんかの親だったら子供を探す
    if( $datum['parent_id'] === 0 ) {
        foreach( $data as $_child_datum ) {
            // 子を見つけたら子として拾っておく
            if( $datum['hoge_id'] == $_child_datum['parent_id'] ) {
                $datum['childs'] []= $_child_datum;
            }
        }
        $listed_data []= $datum;
    }
}
// hoge_id 順にソート.
usort($listed_data,'id_cmp');

// リスト化開始.
$buffer='<ul>';
foreach( $listed_data as $datum ) {
    $buffer.="<li>{$datum['hoge']}";
    if( isset($datum['childs']) ) {
        $buffer.='<ul>';
        $childs = $datum['childs'];
        foreach( $childs as $child ) {
            $buffer.="<li>{$child['hoge']}</li>";
        }
        $buffer.='</ul></li>';
    } else {
        $buffer.='</li>';
    }
}
// リスト表示.
echo $buffer.='</ul>';
```

使い捨てコードなので汚くて済みません。
目的も他のデータパターンがあるのかどうか分かりませんでしたがこれでいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 実際に試してみました。期待通り動作しました

Answer (score 2):

宿題を手伝っている感じがしますが…
オブジェクトを使って、ループ内のコードを簡単にしようとしてます。配列に比べると、オブジェクトだと持ち回しができるのでコードの見通しが良くなると思っています。その代わりHTML変換で再帰呼び出しになってしまいました。

ざっと書いただけなので、ちゃんと書くなら、
・stdClassではなくてHoge用のクラスを使う、
・エラー処理を行う、
など必要なことはたくさんありそうです。

```
// オブジェクトに変換する
$hogeAll = [];
foreach($data as $hoge) {
    $hogeAll[$hoge['hoge_id']] = makeHoge($hoge);
}
// 階層構造を構築する
$root = [];
foreach($hogeAll as $hoge) {
    if($hoge->parent>0) {
        $hogeAll[$hoge->parent]->children[] = $hoge;
    } else {
        $root[] = $hoge;
    }
}
// HTMLに変換する
echo listHoge($root);

/**
 * @param stdClass[] $hogeList
 * @param string     $head
 * @return string
 */
function listHoge(array $hogeList, $head='') {
    $string = "{$head}<ul>";
    foreach($hogeList as $hoge) {
        $string .= "\n{$head}  <li>".$hoge->val;
        if($hoge->children) {
            $string .= "\n{$head}  ".listHoge($hoge->children, "{$head}  ")."\n{$head}";
        }
        $string .= "</li>";
    }
    return $string."\n{$head}</ul>";
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return stdClass
 */
function makeHoge($data) {
    $hoge           = new stdClass();
    $hoge->id       = $data['hoge_id'];
    $hoge->val      = $data['hoge'];
    $hoge->parent   = $data['parent_id'];
    $hoge->children = [];
    return $hoge;
}
```

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。これまでstdClassを使用したことがなかったため、参考になりました